# Where to find papers when Google Scholar and libraries fail?

Tags: publications, research-process

I'm trying to find the following paper:

R.M. Wilson, “Decomposition of a complete graph into subgraphs isomorphic to a given graph.“ Congressus Numerantium XV (1975), 647-659. MR0396347 (53:214)

Also seen cited as:

R.M. Wilson, “Decomposition of a complete graph into subgraphs isomorphic to a given graph.“ Utilitas Math, Winnipeg (1976)

I cannot find it anywhere, online or offline. How am I supposed to progress here?

Comment: In addition to consulting libraries, also consult librarians.  They can often find papers for you housed at other libraries.

Comment: The most complete repositories are probably sci-hub.tw and libgen.rs, but both of those resources infringe on copyright laws (by ignoring them altogether) quite drastically — just be aware of the ethical and legal issues here.

Comment: Perhaps you are from Germany, this may be something to check at http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/924748959. Regarding libgen, I use it without fear.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more appropriate for a Math site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help finding a research paper published 70 years ago, not able to find it anywhere](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/185748/help-finding-a-research-paper-published-70-years-ago-not-able-to-find-it-anywhe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/what-do-you-do-when-you-find-yourselves-with-an-unreadable-inaccessible-paper

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are at a university, you can go to your library and request the article through their document delivery service.  This is a service available through every university library I know of, and a librarian will find a copy one way or another.  There may be a cost; often it is paid by the library, and if this is for research then it should be possible to pay for it through the associated grant.

Comment: Really? Any ILL I've ever submitted as a student has been free. Are faculty charged?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- It depends on the university/library. Some do, some don't. Oxford will charge to fetch a scan of a document they have in storage... (Or did in 2016/2017)

Comment: Yes, even faculty pay at my school, but at 1,50€ a pop it doesn't break the bank. My librarians are AWESOME at finding obscure stuff I want! I also want this paper, too...

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- clearly there is a cost associated - someone is going to pay it. My university (i.e., student's fees) assume the cost up to a reasonably number of requests or assigns it to the research  grant if applicable. Some other do the same and requires a token payment to avoid overuse... (I think that the cost is around 30€ per search).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- at my former university, the library is obligated to charge the department for some weird legal reasons (or so said the librarian). But it is cheap. Probably, handling the payment costs more than the actual value.

Comment: @Rmano Wow, 30 euro is a lot more than token! I'm in a field where I don't have to do these very often, but I did just have to submit like 7 (?) and like I said, I've never been charged for one. They also aren't for a grant, but for my oral exams so I wonder if my dept is being charged behind the scenes or if there's a limit I just haven't hit yet.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- sorry, I explained myself badly --- I think that the *real* cost is around that figure.

Answer (score 16):

Kindly ask all the authors that recently cited that paper ... at least one of them must have a printed copy or a pdf that can be shared privately with you.

Start from [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2018&hl=de&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&cites=2818007291403935765&scipsc=) to look for all citations since 2018

Comment: This is not a bad idea. But asking a librarian or trying harder to find it yourself (as in my answer) might be better.

Comment: @Oliver882  I presume OP already asked librarians, since OP states "I cannot find it anywhere, online or **offline**"... but I also know I may be wrong. :) .
I had similar issue with a paper from a widely cited paper from the beginning of the 90s: too new to be widely found, too old to be readily available in pdf. Solution: the library provided me microfilms (!) and they thaught me how to use the microfilm scanner in the library (!!).

Comment: Actually I assumed OP had not already asked librarians, because if he/she had, the librarian would probably have found it! But I may be wrong too.

Comment: "at least one of them must have a printed copy or a pdf" LOL. Most people cite stuff without reading it first. This citation has probably been copied from paper to paper since the 1970's, without anyone reading it.

Answer (score 7):

Based on similar references elsewhere, I think it is in "Proceedings of the Fifth British Combinatorial Conference". https://lccn.loc.gov/77361732

See reference 4 in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02321683/document

or reference 1 in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016750600870654X

So now you just have to get this proceedings from a library.

I found this by googling "Congressus Numerantium XV" to find out what that was.

Comment: It appears to have been an invited talk too, see http://staff.computing.dundee.ac.uk/kedwards/bcc/past.html#bcc5

Comment: Yea, the relevant library entry is [this one on WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/proceedings-of-the-fifth-british-combinatorial-conference-1975-university-of-aberdeen-aberdeen-july-14-18-1975/oclc/924748959?referer=di&ht=edition#borrow)

Answer (score 1):

The following *may* be useful if you have access: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/pdf/396347.pdf?pg1=MR&s1=53:214&loc=fromreflist

I also found the following citations with slightly more information:

- <sub>https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0097539792229507 [14] R. M. Wilson, *Decomposition of a Complete Graph into Subgraphs Isomorphic to a Given Graph*,</sub> Utilitas Mathematica Publishing, <sub>Winnipeg, MB, 1976, pp. 647–695.</sub>
- <sub>https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0396347:</sub> MR396347 05C99 Wilson, Richard M. <sub>Decompositions of complete graphs into subgraphs isomorphic to a given graph.</sub> Proceedings of the Fifth British Combinatorial Conference (Univ. Aberdeen, Aberdeen, 1975) <sub>, pp. 647–659. Congressus Numerantium, No. XV, Utilitas Math., Winnipeg,</sub> Man., 1976.
- <sub>http://staff.computing.dundee.ac.uk/kedwards/biblio.html (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sA6vqpGSoXkJ:staff.computing.dundee.ac.uk/kedwards/biblio.html): 198. R. M. Wilson, Decomposition of complete graphs into subgraphs isomorphic to a given graph, in *Proceedings of Fifth British Combinatorial Conference (Aberdeen, 1975)*</sub> (eds. C. St. J. A. Nash-Williams & J. Sheehan)<sub>, *Congressus Numerantium*, 15, (1976), pp. 647-659. **MR0396347 (53 #214)**</sub>