# Help finding a research paper published 70 years ago, not able to find it anywhere

Tags: publications, databases

Title : Ein zahlentheoretische-logarithmischer Rechenstab

Author : Ivan Paasche

It's written in German and was published in "MNU. Der Mathematische und Naturwissenschaftliche Unterricht" 6, 26-28 (1953/54)

It's been cited multiple times, but I'm not able to find this paper anywhere, tried searching over multiple academic databases and search engines but failed.

Issues from this publication are [available](https://www.mnu.de/zeitschriften/130-weitere-Hefte) from 2014 onwards but not
for the previous years.

Comment: Have you asked your librarian?

Comment: Chances are that it hasn't been digitised and will only be available by interlibrary loan (which might be done by scanning) from a few libraries in Germany.

Comment: According to Google Scholar the work was published in "Mathematik und Naturwissenschaften im Unterricht" rather than "Unterrichtsblätter für mathematik und naturwissenschaften" (assuming that's what Math. Naturwiss. Unterr stands for). Volume 6 of the latter appears to be from 1900, and is available on Google Books.

Comment: It's written as "Math. Naturwiss. Unterr. 6, 26---28 1953,1954" in citation of other papers, german is not my native language so might have messed up

Comment: Putting the citation in my local library search finds "Der mathematische und naturwissenschaftliche Unterricht". Older volumes should be available through German university libraries.

Comment: Looks like numerous libraries in Germany have it: https://zdb-katalog.de/title.xhtml?idn=01116672X Talk to your local librarian.

Comment: This might ultimately make no difference, but in this context "zahlentheoretische-logarithmischer" looks strange to me; I'd expect "zahlentheoretisch-logarithmischer" (with no "e" at the end of the first word). Google finds more occurrences of the former than the latter, but that might result from a single typo propagating through later citations. Another possibility might be "zahlentheoretischer logarithmischer".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To look for a paper/publication/book, there is one definitive solution, succesful in 99.9999999% of cases:

1. ask the librarians.

Maybe you do not want to contact librarians, because you cannot phone them, you cannot write an email, you cannot visit a library, so you are left with performing these 3 steps:

1. look in the library.
2. ask the librarians.
3. ask researchers who cited it (if you can ask other researchers around the world, you should have first contacted a librarian, anywhere in the world).

But it must be stressed that 2) is the solution in 99.9999999% of the cases, because... if you have an issue with your eye, do you google it or do you make an appointment with an ophthalmologist?

An iterative google search may help you, for example searching part of the title, not the complete title and reference, pinpointing which library has the required object in their catalog. However you may still have to contact the library having the desired publication... therefore you save time by asking the librarian and completely skipping the multiple google research, plus the outcome is most likely to be successful (by asking the librarians).

Comment: Feel free to collectively improve this answer, I tried to flag the question as a duplicate but I could not find any.

Comment: "improve the answer"??? Add a few more 9's? Anyway, lots of librarians can help, even those not specifically in academic libraries. Even my local village librarian is very helpful since they have many contacts.

Comment: This is what librarians (particularly research librarians) live for. The OP would make their day asking them to track down an obscure paper in an even more obscure journal. It’s like finding the Holy Grail for them.

Comment: @Buffy Something like creating a community answer or even a community post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts .
It's quite annoying to see again and again the same question. without a clear easygoing answer. In the early day of my carreer, I become a ninja in google search (well, first geocities and then metacrawler) to look for obscure pieces of informations. Nowadays, you need to be google ninja. Or, back then as today, just get in touch with librarians. They will not know/understand what is inside the document, but they will find it.

Comment: ophthalmologists charge money @EarlGrey

Comment: @user270610 only in some countries... Librarians don't, you get the idea.

Comment: @user270610 they charge money, whether they charge you through taxes (i.e. eveyone can access it) or via a discrete amount (i.e. only who can pay can access it), well, it depends on whether you live in a modern state or in a technological but retrograde country.

Comment: Some places are getting rid of libraries (and librarians)...

Comment: @JonCuster I mean they spent 4 years at Uni training for this very question

Comment: You do realize that probably 99.999999% of the ppl here, if they have an eye problem, they google it, right?

Comment: @DonQuiKong since I cannot decide how the 99.999999% of the ppl here  waste their time, I can only let them know that before spending time on googling (let's say 20 minutes), the best way is to spend the same amount of time contacting a librarian (2 minutes of unsuccesful googling + 18 minutes to write a proper email to the librarians of choice)

Comment: Hyperbole works better without numbers. At least in 1 in a billion cases... ;-)