# Search articles by a specific conference in dblp

Tags: conference, computer-science, literature-search

I am doing a seminar work as part of a Computer science bachelor's degree. One of the first steps is to submit the articles that the seminar work will be based on. The topic I chose is Malware Detection, and so, I have submitted some articles regarding the subject. My instructor has rejected the articles for various reasons (From Workshops and not conferences, not peer reviews, somewhat old etc) and he says over and over again that I need to take the articles from dblp, and suggested some conferences to search by. So I want to submit the following search query in dblp:

> Articles, from recent years, of specific conferences, are peer-reviewed and are on the topic of malware detection.

And another thing I want to know is:

> All conferences from recent years that are on the topic of Cyber Security.

(So that I will have more conferences to search by other than the list my instructor provided)

This can all be done manually, if not possible via dblp search capabilities, but the key functionality I am missing is the free search of an article name **in a context of a specific conference** (i.e only from a specific conference)

How is that possible? Going to dblp, I can only see a free search box with the capabilities of which I can search either by article name or a conference, but not by both. Also searched [here](https://dblp.org/faq/How+to+use+the+dblp+search.html) and found no clear solution.

Example of a conference to search in: icse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pick one article "on topic", look for it on google scholar, and see who is referencing it. Then, look for the venues where those papers have been published in DBLP. I don't think there is any automatic way of doing this.

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but definitely related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/134634/43873  **TL;DR**: Ask your university librarians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the phrase " *venue:X:*" to your query, where X is the name of the conference.

For example, to search for papers with the word "malware" in their title published in the CCS conference:

https://dblp.org/search?q=malware%20venue%3ACCS%3A

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are asking for is outside of the scope of DBLP.

DBLP is a bibliographic database, and that does not include distinguishing conferences and journals by their fields of research. The FAQ even mentions that "it is impossible to tell where a scientific field starts or ends" (see https://dblp.org/faq/1474671.html).

However, when your seminar instructor said that you should take the papers from DBLP, most likely something different was meant, which can be either of the following two points (or both):

- DBLP tends to index all conferences in non-multidisciplinary computer science conferences of at least a moderately good reputation. While this is of course somewhat subjective, whether a publication venue is on DBLP is a fair predictor for whether the papers at the venue should "count".
- DBLP includes links to the publisher's versions of papers, and not to some preprints which sometimes don't have the corrections in the final paper versions included.

Note that interdisciplinary conferences and journals are sometimes included in DBLP, but not always.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. OP asks for searching for papers in a specific conference, not in conferences of a specific field.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Hmm, the OP asked "And another thing I want to know is: All conferences from recent years that are on the topic of Cyber Security." - Admittedly that was sandwiched between two copies of another question that the other answer is answering.