# Expired links to open access resources on the sites of the Linguistic Society of America and CiNii

Tags: publications, journals, language, online-resource, linguistics

[A comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33926/whats-the-grammar-behind-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9B#comment78603_33926) on Japanese SE from a user who has since deleted their account seems to contain some potentially helpful information to me, so I am trying to find the articles suggested by that commenter. Unfortunately said user has disappeared from Stack Exchange altogether and both of the links provided in the comment have apparently expired, [one](http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/elanguage/pragmatics/article/download/354/354-641-1-PB.pdf) pointing to [the Linguistic Society's site](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/), [the other](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/110001057681.pdf?id=ART0001218787&type=pdf&lang=en&host=cinii&order_no=&ppv_type=0&lang_sw=&no=1483413661&cp=) leading to [CiNii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CiNii).

How do I find those papers/articles? Or at least how can I find out their titles? I have tried the Internet Archive and Googling with all the clues that I am able to think of, to no avail.

By the way, I think this question belongs here because open access to academic papers is a whole can of worms that people outside of academia are not necessarily concerned with or care about.

Comment: This is why people should always post full citations of articles, or at the very least DOIs, not just deep links.

Comment: @NateEldredge Couldn't agree more

Comment: related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134634/how-can-i-find-an-old-obscure-or-otherwise-inaccessible-paper-when-the-usual-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CiNii link contains the ID 110001057681.  Searching for this ID number at https://cir.nii.ac.jp/?lang=en yields one hit, an article entitled "The Japanese Adverbial DOOSE" by 武内 道子, 神奈川大学言語研究 (22), 13-30, 1999.  神奈川大学言語研究センター (I don't know Japanese so I am guessing that this is the bibliographic info.)  The number 110001057681 appears to be its NII Article ID, and it has CRID 1520572360067848960.

The other one is possibly some article in [*Semantics and Pragmatics*](https://semprag.org/index.php/sp), but 354-641-1-PB.pdf doesn't seem to match anything in their current article numbering system.  But their search function returned only two articles whose abstracts mentioned "Japanese", and the total number of articles published is small enough that you could probably browse all of the titles.

Comment: Based on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101000000*/http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/elanguage/pragmatics/), I think it's more likely the first link points to an article in _[Pragmatics](https://benjamins.com/catalog/prag)_, but again the current article numbering system seems different. On the bright side, they implemented DOIs!

Comment: Maybe, but *Semantics and Pragmatics* is actually a publication of the Linguistic Society, while *Pragmatics* does not seem to have any affiliation with the society.

Comment: There was an affiliation in the past. Per https://www.linguisticsociety.org/content/elanguage-journal-archive "Volumes 1–21 were made available in open access on the eLanguage platform and are currently published, along with all subsequent content, by John Benjamins at https://benjamins.com/catalog/prag."

Comment: Oh, I see.  I wondered if 354-641 could be page numbers, but it doesn't look like they ever published any 300-page articles.

Comment: Based on the structure of the archived site it seems 354 is some kind of unique article number across different volumes. There are lots of inconsistencies in the apparent numbering scheme, so it's hard to identify which volume this would belong to. However, the paper ["Pragmatics of discourse modality: A case of the Japanese emotional adverb doose"](https://doi.org/10.1075/prag.1.3.04may) in volume 1 seems like a good match in terms of topic.

Comment: @Anyon I was just gonna comment the same thing! Following your helpful tips I realized I could go through all the issues and volumes one by one and check out their content. I am still only half way through but the only one I have seen that seem to match the topic is the one in volume 1 you mention here! Big thank-you to both of you!